# How can I dim LED recessed lights that are on the same switch as two ceiling fans without slowing the fans down?

Tags: ceiling-fan, led, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting, smart-switch

I have 6 LED Dimmable recessed lights on the same switch as two ceiling fans. There are currently two three way switches that control everything. I want to be able to dim the LED lights without slowing the fans or ruining the motors. 
I have read through a few questions here and see discussions on a smart switch. I like that idea but not sure if it will work in my situation and achieve what i'm looking to do or which one to buy.

Open to any and all suggestions. Just don't want to have to find a way to create a new separate switch.

[image: ceiling fan 2 angle 3][image: ceiling fan 2 angle 2][image: ceiling fan 2 angle 1][image: ceiling fan 1 angle 2][image: ceiling fan 1 angle 1][image: switch 2][image: switch 1][image: ceiling fan 1 angle 3]

Comment: well-implemented smart devices (no phone needed) are a life saver in terms of behavior customization, but it can be a bit daunting getting started. If you can post more details about the wiring we can help you determine which type of smarts could help, but we won't recommend specific products.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved, with the breaker for the circuit turned off of course? That'd give us a *far* better idea of what your options are here

Comment: There are two back wires and one red going into the back of the switches. There are also two white whites together with a wire nut in the box but not into the switch. I'll post pictures

Comment: I do not see a way to post a picture here, hopefully my description helps. Also these are metal boxes on a screened in porch. There is a ground screw in the box with ground wire attached. There is no ground wire going to current switches.

Comment: Hi,  we need more information.  Do you want to be able to turn the fans and LEDs on and off separately, or only allow the LEDs to be on when the fans are on?   However, there is no "magic" way to change the power feed to different items on the same circuit without installing a new switch (plain or dimmer).

Comment: I can turn the fans on or off with the pull string if needed. But the issue is if I want to dim the lights and have the fans on at the same time that cannot be done with a dimmer switch from my understanding because it will slow the fans and ruin the motors.

Comment: I believe one solution would be to use "smart" lights that can be controlled with alexa. So I could dim the lights from the app but still have normal on/off switches. But, a few of the holes for lights are obstructed by joist, so I am currently using the slim canless lights. I do not believe they make canless smart lights yet.

Comment: @CaitlinGentry -- hit the [edit] link in "share edit ..." on your post and then use the button that looks like a stylized picture of a mountain and sun to add pictures

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks - pictures added

Comment: Are the cables we see here surface-mounted for their entire length, or do they disappear into the floor or ceiling?  Can you get us photos of the insides of the fan boxes please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel one switch has two cables coming out of the bottom of the box and disappear into the floor. The other has one cable coming from the top that disappears into the ceiling and the other coming from the bottom that disappears into the floor. Will post picture of fan boxes.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel fan box pictures posted. Ceiling fan 1 is the fan that has the yellow romex. The can light also have yellow romex, so guessing this is the fan the lights are run off of. Ceiling Fan 2 has the gray romex similar to what is in the switch boxes. I do know the ceiling fans were here first and the can lights were added later off of the fans.

Answer (score 1):

### Not possible given the way the power reaches the fan

Do not use a dimmer on this fan setup.  The switches must remain plain switches.

The only option I see is to go to some sort of "smart tech" such as Philips HUE bulbs, with a stick-on wireless dimmer control.

Comment: I personally would be more inclined to go to Insteon because that also opens up options for fan control in this situation...